# How do I know that a limaçon is going to inner loop?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I was setting up the graph for this polar function:
r = 1 + 2sin(Θ)

I set up a table incrementing by π/2

Θ__|__r

0____1

π/2____3

π____1

3π/2____-1

2π____1

5π/2____3

3π____1

7π/2____-1

4π____1

My problem Is I set up the plot points on the graph and begin connecting the dots. But there comes a point, where I have it in red that I don't know where it should go, how do I know it's suppose to loop inwards like this? How do I know it's suppose to go through the origin and loop?

This is what I originally thought (connecting the dots):
[image]

And the part in red where I got confused:

[image]

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Are you aware that in $r=\varphi(\theta)$, if $r$ happens to be negative, you have to traace things backwards (not take the absolute value of $r$) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah that's what I thought I did here. So 7π/2 is the same as 3π/2. And since 'r' is -1 that means invert, So the inverted 7π/2 is π/2, right? and we take the abs of -1 so 1? So it's (π/2,1) right?

Comment: One can do in this way, yes.

Comment: No, when the radius is negative you plot on the opposite side of the origin.  If you want to plot it with a positive radius you add $\pi$ to the angle, not subtract it from $2\pi$.  So if you have negative $r$ at $\theta =3\pi /2$ you could plot the positive radius at $\theta=5\pi /2$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you!!!! so much this was confusing me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to plot the points at finer intervals.  $\sin \theta$ has period $2 \pi$ so your table is twice as long as it needs to be.  Here it is with intervals of $\pi/16$ in $\theta$.  I had to convert the points to rectangular to get Excel to plot it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I made a smaller increment, π/4. So I got for the Θ's: 0, π/4, π/2, 3π/4, π, 5π/4, 3π/2.  And for the 'r' values: 1, 1+√(2), 3, 1 + √(2), 1, 1 - √(2), 3. Everything seemed to be going great up until that 3 which sends the line straight down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your last $3$ is wrong.  Note that $1-\sqrt 2 \lt 0$ so that point is on the opposite side of the origin from $\theta$.  $\sin 3\pi /2=-1$, so you should have $r=-1$  You should be getting every fourth point from my plot, starting with the one at $(1,0)$ and proceeding counterclockwise.  I think $\pi /4$ is still a little coarse for this graph.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I think I understand it now from the first plotted point that I have, π/2 increments are a lot easier for me to do on an exam. I think I understand polar graphs better and why it must form this shape, because in polar graphs everything is sort of like in a counter clockwise whirlpool, Everything is forcefully curved counter clockwise so anytime a point needs to be connected it's never a straight linear line, it's always going to curve in a counter clockwise way. I see this visually now.

Comment: It's like everything is being PULLED in a counter clockwise whirlpool.

Comment: I am having another issue with the graph of: r = 4 - 4sin(2Θ). I incremented by π/2 but since there is a 2Θ in there it becomes π/4. So Θ = 0, π/4, π/2, 3π/4, π, 5π/4. For the r's = 4, 0, 4, 8, 4, 0.... But when I graph it, it looks like a rose. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be a two leafed rose.  Since the argument is $2 \theta$ the function is periodic with period $\pi$.  Again your points are far too coarse to see what is going on.  I recommend computing the points in a spreadsheet so you can write the formula once and copy down.  That makes it easy to compute a few dozen points instead of a handful.  The spreadsheet will graph it for you too if you convert them to rectangular.  That is how I got the figure above.